# Would LWE problem be still secure if error were like this $e=2e_1$?

Tags: cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

In the [Learning with error problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_with_errors), if the error term $e$ from equation $b=<a,s>/q+e$ were of this kind $e=2e_1$, where $e_1$ is chosen according to the probability distribution for the LWE problem, it would weaken the problem significantly or the security insured would remain the same ?

Comment: Security would remain the same if $q$ is odd, and would be compromised if $q$ is even. The reason for the former is that you can multiply LWE samples by 2, which doubles the underlying error and retains the uniform distribution of the $a_i$.  If $q$ is even this is not the case, and the $b_i$ are always even so they are easily distinguished from uniform.

Comment: Actually, doubling the error vectors would increase the size of the errors that are introduced, vastly increasing the probability of an overflow (resulting in, say, a decryption failure).  In Lattice terms, by doubling the error vector, you're increasing the probability that the original point isn't actually the nearest one.  You can half $e$ to compensate, but that would make it easier on the attacker...

Comment: @ChrisPeikert It would be nice if you turn your comment into an answer. Related:  http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-should-we-handle-comments-that-are-actually-answers

Answer (score 4):

It will remain same. Here it will not effect the security because 2 is invertible in the prime q field. In case q is not prime then security will be compromised.